# Boost Overload strange behaviour.. how `int (int ), int (std::string )` differs from `int (int ), int (std::string ), std::string (std::string)`?

Tags: c++, boost, overloading, boost-function

So there is that great lib called [OverLoad (link to downloadable svn directory, lib is header only)](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/overload/trunk/libs/overload/). it can accept functions of any types into it and automatically decide which one you are calling. It is like boost function but better.
Here are 2 code samples (browser can view boost svn) [one](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/overload/trunk/libs/overload/examples/example_8a.cpp) [two](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/overload/trunk/libs/overload/examples/example_7b.cpp). and here is my code that does not compile and is based on them:

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/detail/lightweight_test.hpp>

#include <boost/overload.hpp>

using boost::overload; 

template<class out, class in>
out foo(in O )
{
    std::cout << "yes we can!";
    return out();
}

int main()
{
    //// works
    //overload<int (int ), int (std::string )> f;
    //// works
    //int (*foo1) (int ) = &foo<int, int>;
    //int (*foo2) (std::string ) = &foo<int, std::string>;
    //f.set(foo1);
    //f.set(foo2);
    // or we can use
    //// does also work
    //f.set<int (int )>(&foo<int, int>);
    //f.set<int (std::string )>(&foo<int, std::string>);
    ////

    overload<int (int ), int (std::string ), std::string (std::string) > f;
    //// but when we do this
    //f.set<int (int )>(&foo<int, int>);
    //f.set<int (std::string )>(&foo<int, std::string>);
    //f.set<int (std::string )>(&foo<std::string, std::string>);
    //// or this:
    int (*foo1) (int ) = &foo<int, int>;
    int (*foo2) (std::string ) = &foo<int, std::string>;
    std::string (*foo3) (std::string ) = &foo<std::string, std::string>;
    f.set(foo1);
    f.set(foo2);
    f.set(foo3);
    //// we get compile error

    BOOST_ASSERT( f(0) == 1 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( f("hi") == 2 ); // here we get Error  1   error C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments

    return boost::report_errors();
}
```

So I wonder how to get around this issue?

Comment: `@`myWallJSON as I'm sure you've noted by now, starting questions with phrases like `so there is this grate lib XXXX` is not cool on SO. Could you try to put more effort into formatting/presenting your questions? You seem to be asking a lot, without wanting to put in much effort to make the questions palatable. Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload resolution only considers the parameter types; it does not consider the return type.  So, during overload resolution, `int (std::string)` is indistinguishable from `std::string(std::string)`.

Since this library has to rely on the C++ language's overloading capabilities, it too cannot distinguish between the two functions.